# Fill cin with content for the user to edit

Tags: c++, unix

I've been looking the whole day for a way to fill the cin buffer with content that the user could edit afterwise. I may not have been clear here!

Is there any way to get something like this:

`Enter a sentence: The basic sentence that you can edit as you want`

I think it might be related to stringstreams but something like doesn't even compile:

```
   std::string output;
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << "content for the user to edit";
   ss >> std::cin >> output;
```

Do you guys have any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot for reading.

Comment: The correct answer won't directly relate to C++, but will relate to the environment in which your program runs. Please tag this the operating system you care about.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible with standard library components. You will need to use the interface for the terminal that you are targeting, or use a library which does this for you (such as [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'll find another way then!